# Variables in launch configuration snippet

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I have a problem with my launch.json snippet. When I'm using it, it loses **${}** from variable names.

The snippet looks like this:

```
    "Robot Framework: Launch selected test": {
        "prefix": "Robot Framework: Launch selected test",
        "body": [
            "{",
            "    \"type\": \"robotframework-lsp\",",
            "    \"name\": \"Robot Framework: Launch selected test\",",
            "    \"request\": \"launch\",",
            "    \"cwd\": \"${workspaceFolder}\",",
            "    \"target\": \"${file}\",",
            "    \"terminal\": \"none\",",
            "    \"env\": {},",
            "    \"args\": [\"-t\",\"${selectedText}\"],",
            "    \"internalConsoleOptions\": \"openOnSessionStart\"",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": "Robot Framework: Launch selected test"
    }
```

When I paste it, it looks like that:

```
    {
        "type": "robotframework-lsp",
        "name": "Robot Framework: Launch selected test",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "workspaceFolder",
        "target": "file",
        "terminal": "none",
        "env": {},
        "args": ["-t", "selectedText"],
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    }
```

The dollar symbol and brackets are lost in **cwd**, **target** and **args** lines.
Is there any way to prevent this form happening?

Comment: read the doc: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_how-do-i-have-a-snippet-place-a-variable-in-the-pasted-script

Comment: I don't know how I missed that one, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rioV8 answered my question. Answer taken from the vscode docs:

> To have a variable in the pasted script, you need to escape the '$' of the $variable name so that it isn't parsed by the snippet expansion phase.

```
    "Robot Framework: Launch selected test": {
        "prefix": "Robot Framework: Launch selected test",
        "body": [
            "{",
            "    \"type\": \"robotframework-lsp\",",
            "    \"name\": \"Robot Framework: Launch selected test\",",
            "    \"request\": \"launch\",",
            "    \"cwd\": \"\\${workspaceFolder}\",",
            "    \"target\": \"\\${file}\",",
            "    \"terminal\": \"none\",",
            "    \"env\": {},",
            "    \"args\": [\"-t\",\"\\${selectedText}\"],",
            "    \"internalConsoleOptions\": \"openOnSessionStart\"",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": "Robot Framework: Launch selected test"
    }
```